# How can I pause a thread while the state remains Runnable?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I am trying to think of a way to keep a thread running for a few seconds without terminating, keeping the state as Runnable, i.e. without changing the thread state, say to Blocked or Waiting. (This is for a demo I am working on that displays thread states at various times)

One possible solution would be to just spin it in a while loop that does nothing, or does some CPU intensive calculation. This works ok except once you have a fair number of threads, the CPU gets hot.

Another possible solution would be to get a  URL connection stream, but I don't want this to be dependent on an external connection.

Or I could create my own input stream and put a sleep in the read method, but then my thread will sleep when it calls it, moving it to the Timed Waiting state, which is no good.

So none of these solutions are pratical.

Is there some realistic way to do this without spinning the CPU?

Comment: I believe if you put anything inside the thread that needs an external resource like a URL your thread may run into a blocking read and your thread state is wasted. You'll have to use the CPU but if there are many threads all of them would be competing for it so you get waits for runnable threads for free. As a courtesy your threads could reduce the CPU intense calculation if they come in hordes.

Comment: I really don't want to depend on an external resource. We know how gremlins stand ready to attack the moment they smell a demo.

Comment: Imho you can show threads state in thread pool. Maybe core threads are runnable state. I didnt check it but you can try. You can submit task and you can show state as well

Comment: You could engage in blocking I/O with a temporary socket of your own creation. That blocks the thread as far as the OS is concerned, but to the JVM it is still Runnable.

Comment: @user207421 The problem with that approach is that if we use sleep or wait in our artificial blocking method, then the "current thread" used to call that will be in the same waiting state. Unless you meant something else? Please post it as a response, with a snippet of code if you don't mind

Comment: I meant what I said. Engage in blocking I/O with a socket. I didn't say one word about 'artificial blocking method[s]' or `sleep()` or `wait()`. Those are therefore not problems with my suggested approach.

Comment: @user207421 This sounds right - can you post this as an answer, include some code snippet, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code based on the comment above of user207421. It works as requested!

```
package com.vgrazi.javaconcurrentanimated.study;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class IODelay {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new IODelay().call();
}

{
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            System.out.println("Setting up ServerSocket");
            ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(1234);
            Socket socket=serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Request received");
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                try(OutputStream stream=socket.getOutputStream();) {
                    System.out.println("ServerSocket received request");
                    System.out.println("ServerSocket waiting");
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    stream.write(0);
                } catch(IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

private void call() throws IOException {
    Thread currentThread=Thread.currentThread();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(currentThread.getState());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    System.out.println("Setting up client socket");
    Socket socket=new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
    InputStream inputStream=socket.getInputStream();
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    inputStream.read();
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

}

Comment: The connect and read and write are all pointless. Just set a timeout on the server socket and call `accept()`, then when it times out call `close()`.